# Cannot cabal install hs3 (for haskell-supercollider)

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, cabal, supercollider

(Ubuntu 12.04)

Hello!
I'm trying to get hs3 installed to my haskell platform so that I can use the **haskore-supercollider package** (it's a required dependency). However, when I attempt **cabal install**, it crashes on the some files I believe to be related to hosc. Here's a text readout of the error:

Sound/SC3/UGen/Help.hs:26:46: Not in scope: `lookupEnv'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hsc3-0.15 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1

I've attempted a number of things including updating cabal, reinstalling hosc, and throwing some flags on the install, or getting the install from a different source (slavepianos.org). Still though, I keep getting the same error. Here's an image of the error for reference:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGEKx.png

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have reached "Cabal Hell".

It looks to me like `hsc3` for versions later than 0.13 depends on GHC being at least version 7.6 (the version which added the `lookupEnv` function), while Ubuntu 12.0.4 provides 7.4.  This shows up as a compilation error because `hsc3` has a badly set version bound on the `base` package.

You might try either of:

- Installing a later version of GHC. It's currently at 7.8 with 7.10 expected out next month.
- Using the older `haskore-supercollider` version 0.2, which uses `hsc3` 0.13. (Alas, when I try this with `--dry-run`, cabal fails to find an installation plan, but perhaps it works better if you *actually* have GHC 7.4.)

Comment: That's strange, considering I only installed GHC the other day (last week). Is there a way I can make sure this doesn't happen if I start with a clean slate?

Comment: Bummer, I'm on 7.4.1. Luckily, I'm still pretty new to the language, so I haven't gotten 'settled' yet. I'll try to reinstall and report back. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @RockMan Ubuntu tries to give you "stable" versions of programs. This does not work well with Haskell where many (not all!) developers only cater to the latest versions of GHC and other libraries. If you want to try out new versions of stuff, you might have better luck installing GHC directly from `haskell.org`.

Comment: BTW it's pretty hotly debated in the Haskell community what actually *is* the best way to install and use GHC. It depends a lot on how much you want to be able to use the newest packages, and how much you want to avoid trouble when installing stuff.

Comment: Getting a newer GHC fixed it! Thanks for your help!